# SQL Server 2012: parse XML then pick one of subnodes as well as concat all sub nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, cross-apply

I am trying to parse XML column and trying to do two things

- Iterate through multiple sub nodes of a node and pick one node based on a 1/0 flag value.
- combine all sub nodes to create a one combined field (delimited)

Runnable code block - SQL Server 2012:

```
create table #temp (XMLData xml)

insert into #temp (XMLData)
values ('
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    <PID>111</PID>
    <Languages>
      <Language>German</Language>
      <speak>Y</speak>
      <read>Y</read>
      <write>Y</write>
    </Languages>
    <Languages>
      <Language>Spanish</Language>
      <speak>Y</speak>
      <read>N</read>
      <write>N</write>
    </Languages>
    <phone>
      <PhoneNumber>(101)111-1111</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Work</PhoneType>
      <IsPrimary>1</IsPrimary>
    </phone>
    <phone>
      <PhoneNumber>(101)111-2222</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Mobile</PhoneType>
      <IsPrimary>0</IsPrimary>
    </phone>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    <PID>222</PID>
    <phone>
      <PhoneNumber>(101)222-1111</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Mobile</PhoneType>
      <IsPrimary>0</IsPrimary>
    </phone>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <IsActive>1</IsActive>
    <PID>333</PID>
    <phone>
      <PhoneNumber>(101)333-1111</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Phone</PhoneType>
      <IsPrimary>0</IsPrimary>
    </phone>
    <phone>
      <PhoneNumber>(101)333-2222</PhoneNumber>
      <PhoneType>Mobile</PhoneType>
      <IsPrimary>1</IsPrimary>
    </phone>
    <location>
      <location-state>NY</location-state>
    </location>
    <location>
      <location-state>DC</location-state>
    </location>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
')

select 
      c.value('IsActive[1]','varchar(1)') as IsActive
    , c.value('PID[1]','varchar(5)') as PID
    , case when c.value('phone[1]/IsPrimary[1]','int') = 1 then c.value('phone[1]/PhoneNumber[1]','varchar(15)') end as  PublicWorkPhone /** this condition needs to look at all sub nodes. this stops at the first one.  **/
    , c.value('location[1]','varchar(2)') as location
from   
    #temp 
    cross apply #temp.XMLData.nodes('/Report_Data/Report_Entry') as y(c)

drop table #temp
GO
```

I get this:

```
IsActive PID   PublicWorkPhone location
-------- ----- --------------- --------
1        111   (101)111-1111   NULL
1        222   NULL            NULL
1        333   NULL            NY
```

However, I need this:

```
IsActive PID   PublicWorkPhone location
-------- ----- --------------- --------
1        111   (101)111-1111   NULL
1        222   NULL            NULL
1        333   (101)333-2222   NY,DC
```

For PID=333, the primary phone is (101)333-2222 and not null. 
Also, the location should be "NY,DC" not just NY.

I'd really appreciate any help you could offer achieving the result. 
Thank you

Comment: This is a good question: Copy'n'pasteable test scenario, own effort, wrong output, expected output. +1 from my side

Comment: @Shnugo, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH prep AS 
(
  SELECT 
    c.value('(IsActive[1]/text())[1]','char(1)') as IsActive,
    c.value('(PID[1]/text())[1]','varchar(5)') as PID,
    c.value('(phone[IsPrimary=1]/PhoneNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(15)') AS PublicWorkPhone,
    location = cc.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
  from #temp 
  CROSS APPLY #temp.XMLData.nodes('/Report_Data/Report_Entry') as y(c)
  OUTER APPLY c.nodes('location/location-state') AS z(cc)
)
SELECT
  IsActive, 
  PID,
  PublicWorkPhone,
  Location = 
  STUFF ((
    SELECT ',' + location
    FROM prep pp
    WHERE p.PID = pp.PID
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM prep p
GROUP BY IsActive, PID, PublicWorkPhone;
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion uses `XQuery` in `.nodes()` to find the phone node, which is the *primary*, and the `XQuery`-function `data()` for your locations. This function will return with all included text parts separated by a blank (Btw: It's strange, that one cannot pass in the separator char...). In your case I expect *solid-two-char* location codes. Simply replace the blank with a comma and that's it...

```
SELECT re.value(N'IsActive[1]','bit') AS IsActive
      ,re.value(N'PID[1]','int') AS PID
      ,ph.value(N'PhoneNumber[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PublicWorkPhone
      ,REPLACE(re.query(N'data(location/location-state)').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),' ',',') AS location
FROM #temp AS tmp
CROSS APPLY tmp.XMLData.nodes(N'/Report_Data/Report_Entry') AS A(re)
OUTER APPLY re.nodes(N'phone[IsPrimary=1]') AS B(ph);
```

Comment: thank you for helping with my request. I will use your replace logic to get the NY,DC. That way I am working with just one table.

Comment: @sch I do not quite understand, what your *That way I am working with just one table* means actually, but I'm glad, that you found a solution! Please allow me one hint: The SO-way of saying *Thank you* is voting and acceptance. You accepted the other answer. This is perfectly OK and fully up to you. Since you've crossed the 15 rep points border you are additionally allowed to vote. Votes are counted for badges and privileges.

Comment: I voted your answer up. I accepted the other solution as it solved the problem for me as is. when  a phone was not available it was returning `NULL values IsActive PID   PublicWorkPhone Location`
`-------- ----- --------------- ---------`
`1        111   (101)111-1111   NULL`
`1        222   NULL            NULL`
`1        333   (101)333-2222   NY,DC`

vs

`IsActive PID   PublicWorkPhone location`
`-------- ----- --------------- ---------`
`1        111   (101)111-1111`   
`1        222   NULL            `
`1        333   (101)333-2222   NY,DC`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to Answer my request. I just crossed the 15 rep points. What I mean by another table is, #temp, Cross apply and outer apply will create 3 separate tables in memory and join them. The CTE approach suggested by Adam adds another to the mix. I am trying to figure out which would be faster, as I will apply this code to several xml files with about .5 million records. However its one time only, so it might not be that big a deal.

Comment: @sch Ah, I see... A `#temp`-table will create a side table, but the CTE, as well as the APPLYs, are fully inlined! My solution is pure *ad-hoc* SQL, no created side tables needed at all, just derived tables. It's the engine's decision how to deal with this. And the engine does a great job with this! You can compare the actual execution plans to find this out...